# While publishing an page getting this error 'An error occurred while rendering Page 'Index' (tcm:5-5681-64)'

Tags: publishing

While publishing an page I am getting this error the below error
'An error occurred while rendering Page 'Index' (tcm:5-5681-64)'

I have created everything from scratch except publication like schema, component, component template and page only Metadata Schema re-use as provided by tridion sites defaults

Comment: This sounds like a template error. You could try to preview the page (or the component) and see if you get any more details on the error message. Alternatively, using Template Builder to check what is running, but that may be more advanced than what you need at the moment. If you find more error details please update your post with that.

Comment: you may also find exception in windows event viewer on the publisher server.

Comment: +1 to a possible template issue. When publishing, the Content Manager gathers other items to publish (in a _resolving_ step) and then runs the Page and Component Templates against the resolved items in the _rendering_ part of publishing. You could adjust the templates or try removing/adjusting the "non-default" Building Blocks to help locate the issue.